# PyCharm: add folder to the project

Tags: pycharm

I just want to add a folder with some files to the current project tree view without adding `.idea` to that folder. I tried to read intro to the projects organization in PyCharm and looked for similar questions, but still don't knonw what to do. Is the "excluded files" the needed feature?

I confese I'm lacking some deeper knowledge how projects works in PyCharm, but to be honest, really intuitive the thing is not, isn't it?
PyCharm pro 2021.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add external folders to the current project, simply go to `File > Settings > Project: "projectName" > Project Structure` and on the right side click the `+ Add content root` button. Doing this should not create any aditional `.idea` folder as they are (usually) only created once per project.

Comment: looks like exactly what I wanted